# How to Enter data for only conditioned rows on data table

Tags: r, data.table

I need to put number on first or random item in the group.
I do following:

```
item<-sample(c("a","b", "c"), 30,replace=T)
week<-rep(c("1","2","3"),10)
volume<-c(1:30)
DT<-data.table(item, week,volume)
setkeyv(DT, c("item", "week"))

sampleDT <- DT[,.SD[1], by= list(item,week)]
   item week volume newCol
1:    a    1      1      5
2:    a    2     14      5
3:    a    3      6      5
4:    b    1     13      5
5:    b    2      2      5
6:    b    3      9      5
7:    c    1      7      5
8:    c    2      5      5
9:    c    3      3      5

DT[DT[,.SD[1], by= list(item,week)], newCol:=5]
```

The sampleDT comes out correct ,but last line puts 5 on all columns instead of conditioned ones.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to do this instead:

```
DT[DT[, .I[1], by = list(item, week)]$V1, newCol := 5]
```

Your version doesn't work because the join that you have results in the full `data.table`.

Also there is a pending FR to make the syntax simpler:

```
# won't work now, but maybe in the future
DT[, newCol[1] := 5, by = list(item, week)]
```

Comment: Never thought I would say this about `R` syntax, but that second command looks very swish!

Comment: Thank you, it worked. $V1 looks like new column created.

Comment: @user1555785 look at the output of `DT[, .I[1], by = list(item, week)]` and the `$V1` part should be clear

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your command is that it is finding rows in the original `data.table` that have combinations of the keys `[item, week]` that you found in `sampleDT`. Since `sampleDT` includes all combinations of `[item, week]`, you get the whole `data.table` back.

A simpler solution (I think) would be using `!duplicated()` to retrieve the first instance of each `[item, week]` combination:

```
DT[!duplicated(DT, c("item", "week") ), newCol := 5]
```